# Как подменить звук поступающий через микрофон? OS X

Tags: xcode, bash, macos, аудио, звукозапись

Как подменить звук поступающий через микрофон, например голос? Так, чтобы в других программах, использующих микрофон, на вход уже поступала подмененный мною звук. Звук необходимо подменять в режиме реального времени. Буду играть с трансформацией голоса.

Можно ли это сделать только средствами XCode, или нужно контачить XCode со всякими баш скриптами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть примочки, создающие виртуальные аудиоустройства в системе и коммутацию аудио – например, [SoundFlower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) или [Jack](http://jackaudio.org/). Для второго даже открыты [исходники](https://github.com/jackaudio).

В программах, работающих со звуком, напр. Skype™, можно выбирать, с каких устройств брать звук (не обязательно микрофон), и на какие выводить (колонки / наушники).

В вашей программе, видимо, надо создать виртуальное устройство, которое будет брать микрофонный сигнал на вход, а выход вашего преобразователя направлять на выход вирт. устройства. Этот выход и будет выбран в качестве аудио-источника в настройках звука в Skype™.

Comment: Спасибо за напутствие. Но хотелось бы подменить работу микрофона, а в дальнейшем и веб-камеры на свои аудио и видеопотоки.